# CMAKE thrift generated files compiler options

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to compile generated `thrift` code into my source. The `thrift` stuff is generated into `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` then I add generated cpp files into my library, with `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${ThriftGeneratedFiles} PROPERTIES
    GENERATED 1
    COMPILE_OPTIONS ""
)`

Then I add the include path to generated files using `TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` with `SYSTEM` keyword. When I'm trying to compile it, since my module compiles with `-Wsuggest-override` it fails to compile the generated cpp file with `can be marked override [-Werror=suggest-override]`. I dont get why, isnt the `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES` should solve this problem?
CMake file snippet

```
ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS(
        ...
        ...
        -Wsuggest-override
        ...
        ...
)
FIND_PROGRAM(THRIFT_COMPILER thrift ${_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR}/buildtrees/thrift/x64-linux-rel/compiler/cpp/bin/ NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
SET(ThriftOutputDir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/thrift/gen/)
FILE(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${ThriftOutputDir})

SET(ThriftGeneratedFiles
    ${ThriftOutputDir}/MyServer.cpp
    ${ThriftOutputDir}/My_types.cpp
    ${ThriftOutputDir}/My_constants.cpp
    )

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT
        generated.timestamp
        COMMAND
        ${THRIFT_COMPILER} --gen cpp:no_default_operators -out ${ThriftOutputDir} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/protocols/My.thrift
        WORKING_DIRECTORY
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating source code from Thrift definition")
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(RunThriftCompiler
                  DEPENDS
                  generated.timestamp
                  COMMENT "Checking if re-generation is required")

ADD_LIBRARY(MyProject SHARED
            ${SOURCES}
            ${ThriftGeneratedFiles}
            )

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${ThriftGeneratedFiles} PROPERTIES
                            GENERATED 1
                            COMPILE_OPTIONS ""
                            )
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(MyProject SYSTEM PRIVATE
                           ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR}
                           ${ThriftOutputDir}
                           )
```

Compilation message:

> cd
>   /home/user/Development/Project/Project16/cmake-build-debug/lib/MyProject
>   && /usr/bin/c++  -DCARES_STATICLIB -DMyProject_EXPORTS
>   -I/home/user/Development/Project/Project16/lib/include/MyProject -I/home/user/Development/Project/Project16/lib/include -isystem /home/user/Development/Project/Project16/cmake-build-debug/ext/etcd
>   -isystem /home/user/Development/Project/Project16/cmake-build-debug/protocols
>   -isystem /home/user/Development/Project/Project16/ext/spdk/include -isystem /home/user/Development/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include -isystem /home/user/Development/Project/Project16/cmake-build-debug/lib/MyProject/thrift/gen
>   -g -fPIC   -include MyProject.h -fPIC -fstrict-aliasing -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mtune=core-avx-i -mavx -march=core-avx-i -fno-plt -g -fstack-protector-all -fstack-check -rdynamic -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=unused -Wno-error=unused-but-set-parameter -Wshadow -Werror=address -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=char-subscripts -Werror=enum-compare -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=comment -Werror=format -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=nonnull -Werror=pointer-sign -Werror=reorder -Werror=return-type -Werror=sequence-point -Wstrict-aliasing=1 -Werror=strict-overflow=1 -Werror=switch -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=uninitialized -Werror=unknown-pragmas -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-value -Werror=volatile-register-var -Werror=clobbered -Werror=empty-body -Werror=ignored-qualifiers -Werror=sign-compare -Werror=type-limits -Werror -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wswitch-bool -Wlogical-not-parentheses -Wsizeof-array-argument -Wbool-compare -Wtype-limits -Waddress -Wmisleading-indentation -Wshift-negative-value -Wtautological-compare -Wnull-dereference -Wduplicated-cond -Wnonnull -Wnonnull-compare -Wignored-qualifiers -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wparentheses -Wsequence-point -Wno-return-local-addr -Wreturn-type -Wtrigraphs -Wunused-local-typedefs -Winvalid-memory-model -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas -Wframe-address -Wtrampolines -Wfloat-equal -Wno-free-nonheap-object -Wold-style-cast -Wunused-parameter -Wunused -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wframe-larger-than=1100000 -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wclobbered -Wenum-compare -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wmemset-transposed-args -Wlogical-op -Wredundant-decls -Winvalid-pch -Wvarargs -Wvector-operation-performance -Wvolatile-register-var -Wdisabled-optimization -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wodr -Wplacement-new=2 -Wdelete-incomplete -Wsized-deallocation -Wno-virtual-move-assign -Wsuggest-override -DBOOST_COROUTINES_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING -DGTEST_LINKED_AS_SHARED_LIBRARY -D_GNU_SOURCE -DIGNORE_VALIDATION= -std=gnu++1z -o CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/thrift/gen/MyProject_constants.cpp.o -c
>   /home/user/Development/Project/Project16/cmake-build-debug/lib/MyProject/thrift/gen/MyProject_constants.cpp
>   In file included from
>   /home/user/Development/Project/Project16/cmake-build-debug/lib/MyProject/thrift/gen/MyProject_types.cpp:7:0:
>   /home/user/Development/Project/Project16/cmake-build-debug/lib/MyProject/thrift/gen/MyProject_types.h:72:15:
>   error: ‘virtual const char* MyProject::ThriftCapiException::what()
>   const’ can be marked override [-Werror=suggest-override]    const
>   char* what() const throw();

As seen, all compilation flags are applied.

Comment: Plese, show **complete** error message, which contans info about which file is compiled, include chain and so on.

Comment: "since my module compiles with `-Wsuggest-override`" - Do you set this option via `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable? If so, the option is applied to **every** `.cpp` file; `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property doesn't include options from `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable.

Comment: I set it using ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS, should it work?

Comment: And there is no property `COMPILE_OPTIONS` for *source files*: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-source-files. The property exists only for *targets* and *directories*. You may create an [OBJECT library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) from thrift-generated sources. For that library you may set (that is, clear) `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property. Then, use resulted objects files in your main library.

Comment: you are right. I guess it should be `COMPILE_FLAGS`?

Comment: No, [COMPILE_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_sf/COMPILE_FLAGS.html) source file property contains only *additional* flags, that is clearing it doesn't cancel the flags applied for the whole target.

Comment: Yep, already figured that out. Would you like to hint what is the proper solution for such a situation?

Comment: You probably have read [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517977/cmake-thrift-generated-files-compiler-options?noredirect=1#comment91976403_52517977) before I have updated it. Please, re-read it.

Comment: you are right, I've missed this update, will try it right away

Comment: worked like a charm. please convert your comment to the answer

Comment: OK, I will do that later. At the time, could you update your question post with the information you have posted in the comments? I mean using `ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS` command for add `-Wsuggest-override` compiler option. As I said before, it is important that you use this function for adding the option (and not `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable).

Comment: Added the `ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS`, anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties on **source files** like `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` and `COMPILE_FLAGS` may only **add** a compile option. Using these properties it is impossible to *overwrite* (*delete*) compile options for the target. (And options added by `ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS` are eventually assigned for the target).

You may create an `OBJECT` library from thrift-generated sources. For that library you may set (that is, clear) [COMPILE_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) property. Resulted object files can be used then in your main library:

```
# Object files for thrift-generated sources
add_library(thriftGenerated OBJECT ${ThriftGeneratedFiles})
# For these files clear compile options which has been set before
set_property(TARGET thriftGenerated PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS)

# Then use object files for thrift-generated sources in other library
add_library(MyProject SHARED
    ${SOURCES}
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:thriftGenerated>
)
```